# Terminology for the symmetric vector product on the Bloch sphere

Tags: vectors, notation, bloch-sphere

I was reading the paper "*The extended Bloch representation of quantum mechanics and the hidden-measurement solution to the measurement problem*" by **Diederik Aerts**, **Massimiliano Sassoli de Bianchi**.

There the authors define two vector products in $\mathbb{R}^{N^2-1} $, which are:

A symmetric product
$$ (\mathbf{u} \star  \mathbf{v} )_i= \frac{c_N}{N-2} \sum_{j,k=1}^{N^2-1} d_{ijk} u_j v_k$$

and

an anti-symmetric product
$$ (\mathbf{u} \wedge  \mathbf{v} )_i=  \sum_{j,k=1}^{N^2-1} f_{ijk} u_j v_k$$

Where $d_{ijk}$ is the symmetric and $f_{ijk}$ is the anti-symmetric *structure constant* from Lie algebras, given three generators $A_i$,$B$ and $C$, $[A_i,B_j]=2i \sum_{k=1}^{N^2-1} f_{ijk}C_k$, so, $f_{ijk}$ is the a totally anti-symmetric structure constant. Also, $\{A_i,B_j\}=\frac{4}{N}\delta_{ij} \mathbb{I}+ 2 \sum_{k=1}^{N^2-1} d_{ijk}C_k$

And

$$C_N \equiv \sqrt{\frac{N(N-1)}{2}}$$

The second product I know is the wedge product of two vectors.

**My question is:** *Does anyone know what is the name of the first product? What kind of product is it? Or what kind of notation is this?*

I looked at least 15 books and other articles which have this same product, but I could not find its name or what it is.

Comment: Could it be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor#Symmetric_product ?

Comment: @Emil I do not know if it is the symmetric product of tensors, at least I can not see it.

Comment: Could it have some relationship to the [Moyal product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_product) that uses the same five-pointed-star symbol?

Comment: Guess it has something to do with $SU(N)$ because that has similar or maybe same structure constants.

Comment: I think the square root is just a convention, it probably shows up in a related factor too, right? Because it looks like the square root of a factor that pops up in combinatorics sometimes. Maybe the other is an overcounting factor.

Comment: Does it use a metric like here? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2998541/68036 Thought the formulas looked similar. Perhaps it is a basis expansion of some sort...

Comment: @Emil Thanks for your help! But I sent an email to one of the paper's authors. And he replied to me writing this: " I have noticed that when it is given a name, it is simply called "symmetric star product" in some articles. It is just a product defined by using the symmetric tensor obtained from the structure constants of the SU(N) generators, in the same way as the "wedge product" (or more precisely "antisymmetric wedge product") also appearing in the formula in question is also defined by using the antisymmetric tensor obtained from the structure constants of the SU(N) generators."

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks for your help! But I sent an email to one of the paper's authors. And he replied to me writing this: " I have noticed that when it is given a name, it is simply called "symmetric star product" in some articles. It is just a product defined by using the symmetric tensor obtained from the structure constants of the SU(N) generators, in the same way as the "wedge product" (or more precisely "antisymmetric wedge product") also appearing in the formula in question is also defined by using the antisymmetric tensor obtained from the structure constants of the SU(N) generators."

Comment: The doi of that flighty 2014 paper in question is [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2014.09.020). The symmetrized product is distinctly  and incontrovertibly unrelated to the Moyal product. In the summation over repeated indices convention, $d_{ijk}u^iv^jw^k$ is the celebrated cubic invariant for SU(N), N>2, and when all three adjoint reps coincide, the cubic Casimir invariant of the rep. SU(3) technology is brimming with such symmetrizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things become clearer if the *symmetric product* or *anti-commutator* is defined directly in the *real* vector space $V$ (or more precisely: in the non-associative algebra) of *traceless* self-adjoint (complex) matrices with scalar product $\langle A,B\rangle = \frac{1}{2} Tr(A, B)$, rather than in "component space" with respect to a basis $\{\Lambda_1,\dots,\Lambda_{N^2-1} \}$.

So let $A, B \in V$. The *anti-commutator* is defined by
$[A,B]_{+} = AB+BA$. The $i$-component with respect to the given basis is obtained by projection on $\Lambda_i$, i.e., by calculating  $\langle [A,B]_{+}, \Lambda_i \rangle$.

Setting $A=\sum_{j=1}^{N^2-1} u_j \Lambda_j$ and $B=\sum_{k=1}^{N^2-1} v_k \Lambda_k$ yields the symmetric product in component space (your first equation) up to a constant factor.

Hint (if necessary) : use the definitions and in particular

$$[\Lambda_j, \Lambda_k]_+ = \frac{4}{N} \delta_{jk} I + 2\sum_{l=1}^{N^2-1} d_{jkl} \Lambda_l$$ and
$$\langle \Lambda_l \Lambda_i \rangle = \delta_{li}.$$

Personnally, I find it is quite pragmatic that the name of a product doesn't change if it is expressed with respect to a given basis.